# Why is folic acid very slightly soluble in water while it's a B vitamin?

Tags: biochemistry, solubility

The solubility of folic acid is just [1.6 mg/L (25 °C)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folate).

Why is it so insoluble in water while it is one of B vitamins which are called water-soluble vitamins beside Vitamin C?

Comment: You don't need much of it - 400 micrograms could still be dissolved in a glass of water.

Comment: But when we say a compound is *water-soluble* we are saying it has a significance solubility in water.

Comment: What's the solubility of the so-called water-insoluble vitamins ?

Comment: The structure with two acid groups and at least one amine suggests that the solubility is pH dependent. Water soluble or fat soluble is determined by the ability of the body to store vitamins in fat cells or possibly the liver and to transport them from the intestines. The concentration of folate in the blood is much lower than the solubility limit. It is hard to make definitive conclusions on one data snippet.

Comment: Folate is a supplement and vitamer, see [e. g. here](https://proteopedia.org/wiki/index.php/Dihydrofolate_reductase). More important than absolute solubility is the ratio of solubilities in water and octanol, or log POW.

Comment: Of course folate/folic acid (vitamin B9) is just one of the examples. There are other B vitamins too that are very slightly soluble in water; such as riboflavin (vitamin B2).

Comment: Well, that's what you get if one tries to categorise stuff arbitrarily. Still, as I said you could live on  folic acid dissolved in water, while I seriously doubt the same can be told about vit. A, for example.

Comment: Consider that sodium folate  is more soluble that folic acid. similar as sodium palmitate (soap) is more soluble than palmitic acid.

Comment: But they don't mention salts of vitamins when speaking about the solubility of vitamins. Also, let's compare solubilities of ascorbic acid and sodium ascorbate. Vitamin C has a solubility of $330$ g/L, while its sodium salt has a solubility of $62$ g/L. See? Its sodium salt is even less soluble. Also, we get several solubilities with different cations. So it's not very good to measure the solubility of vitamins as salts. Some of them aren't even acids to produce salts.

Comment: Oh, by the way, solubility of sodium palmitate is also less than that of palmitic acid! At least $4.6$ mg/L for the acid (in 0 °C), and $120$ μg/L for the salt. (So palmitic acid is even more soluble than folic acid!)

Comment: Ascorbic acid is called a water-soluble vitamin (vitamin C) and its solubility in water is $330$ g/L.

Comment: You better have some real good data on this "sodium palmitate is also less than that of palmitic acid" because it's nonsense. You ever seen insoluble sodium soap? I doubt that.